# Textbox with Dropdown as Group Addon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the Dropdown as a Group Add-on in bootstrap:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCountryCode, new SelectList(Model.ListOfCountries, "PhoneCode", "PhoneCode"), "Select")</div>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Value, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the result I get:

[image]

Is there another way to do this so my styles of dropdown are same as the textbox?

I don't want the grey part around the dropdown.

Here is a JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mdawood1991/yLygh0v4/

Comment: When I use view CSS, "input-group-addon" appears to have the background color set to gray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best way to fix this. Style the *dropdown* with this:

```
background: transparent; 
border: 0;
```

Then it'll look like this:

[image: Dropdown merged into background]

And when open:

[image: Open dropdown merged into background]

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `input-group-btn` dropdown:

```
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-expanded="false">Select <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">0044</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">0033</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">001</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /btn-group -->
```

[**Fiddle.**](https://jsfiddle.net/yLygh0v4/3/)

---

Or, you can remove the padding from the `.input-group-addon`:

```
.input-group-addon {
    padding: 0 !important;
    background: transparent;
}
```

[**Fiddle.**](https://jsfiddle.net/yLygh0v4/4/)

Comment: I don't think this will post back the selected dropdown value from the Form

Comment: No it wont. You can keep a hidden input, and change its value when the dropdown's value is changed. Otherwise, you can simply [remove the padding from the addon](https://jsfiddle.net/yLygh0v4/4/).

Answer (score 0):

What about styling the select box?

```
select{
background-color: transparent;
}
```

It may be that I got your question wrong :)

The area then just vanishes on my phone. I'm using safari on iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the background color for that class:

```
.input-group-addon {
    background: white;
}
```

Or just change it in the existing CSS.